# Matrix multiplication with bitwise operators

Tags: python, linear-algebra, theano, matrix-multiplication

I want to create a bitmask vector that masks which values are greater than a given value. Something like [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] * [>3, >3, >3, >3, >3] = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]. I want to be able to run this on theano to get faster computation time for matrix operations. Is there a linear algebra procedure that can be written using bitwise operators or bits to create this bitmask? I am currently looping through this matrix and I would like to move the computation to a GPU using theano which requires more matrix multiplication. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Subtract 3 from you vector and look at the sign bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get exactly what you want with logical operations between matrices.
For example

```
print((np.r_[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] > 3))
```

will give

```
[False False False  True  True]
```

And if you want integers you can do

```
print((np.r_[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] > 3).astype(int) )
```

and get

```
[0 0 0 1 1]
```